# Can you launch non-ROS programs from a .launch file?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My workflow requires launching ROS nodes as well as other programs. This results in the "many terminal" problem :) Is there a way to launch these non-ROS executables from a launch file, too?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9161/can-you-launch-non-ros-programs-from-a-.launch-file?/) by [Angelica](https://answers.ros.org/users/166/angelica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-10-05**:
#q272267 has an answer similar to both of these but with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch might add extra parameters like __name and __log.
The non-ros executable should be able to handle those (by ignoring)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another possibility would be to write a little wrapper program that calls whatever program you'd like; by using the ros init stuff, it could parse out the roslaunch arguments, and do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aschaefer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38195/aschaefer/) on 2018-10-24**:
The [aliencontrol ROS package](https://github.com/acschaefer/aliencontrol) is a generic wrapper that can launch any external script or executable. You might want to give it a try.